# Missing routes after upgrading Laravel 5.1 to 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

After I upgraded Laravel from 5.1 to 5.2

```
php artisan route:list
```

returns andempty list of routes. Also I got this error:

> NotFoundHttpException

The file `routes.php` is in the `app\Http` folder. It seems that the file "routes.php" is not visible at all.

Comment: check laravel [Upgrade Guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0)

Comment: Going off of your Route in the comments below, try: `Route::get('/', 'HomeController@home')->name('home-page');` Does this work?

Comment: No. it seems that routes is not been autoloaded

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `Route::controller`? Laravel 5.2 deprecated that.

> Implicit controller routes using Route::controller have been deprecated. Please use explicit route registration in your routes file. This will likely be extracted into a package.

Comment: No. How start my routes.php Route::group(['before' => 'csrf'], function () {
  Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home-page', 'uses' => 'HomeController@home']);

Comment: You have instructions [step by step](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0) how to upgrade from 5.1 to 5.2. Check if you missed any step

Comment: Routes in Laravel 5 deprecated the `filters`in favour of `middlewares, try removing that group

Comment: I deleted all from routes.php and left only "Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home-page', 'uses' => 'HomeController@home']);,", but no succes. It seems that the file "routes.php" is not visible at all. I following all instruction.